# How to find the mean and variance of an AR(1)-GARCH(1,1) model?

Tags: variance, mean, econometrics, autoregressive, garch

The AR(1)-GARCH(1,1) model is defined as,

[image]

I understand how to find the unconditional variance of at.

How would I find the mean and variance of yt in this model, assuming I know the variance of at.

Comment: what did you try already? show your work

Comment: the unconditional variance of the garch model or at is
w/ (1- (α+ β))
so u have the variance of at, would i just find the variance of yt then using the variance formula?